# AngularJS instant URL loading

Tags: angularjs

this question may sound noob to geeks with `ng-expert` tag in their shirts.

I've been seeing some AngularJS-based sites that whenever I clicked a link, the URL changes but the browser does not load, it only loads dynamic content to their `ng-view`.

If current URL is `http://www.sample.com/` and I clicked on **Contact us** link, the URL at my browser becomes `http://www.sample.com/contact-us` and so the page content changes like Ajax load but the browser does not load.

That thing is kind of new to me, can someone enlighten me about this? I've seen several tutorials but links are only hashtag-based (`http://www.sample.com/#contactus`) and not route based.
I don't know what specific Angular concept it is so I don't know what to look for.

I'll greatly appreciate constructive solid answers. Thanks!

Comment: You can start by checking out the [`$location` service](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location), especially the part about "HTML5 mode". Do note that URL rewriting is required in the server-side to support this.

Comment: Thanks @NikosParaskevopoulos for that link reference. I have Laravel as back-end :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do routing with angular js without hash tags, by setting

```
   // use the HTML5 History API    
   $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

so your browser url becomes `http://www.sample.com/contact-us` not `http://www.sample.com/#contact-us`

here is the complete tutorial blog,
https://scotch.io/quick-tips/pretty-urls-in-angularjs-removing-the-hashtag

Answer (score 1):

You can change pages dynamically by changing the HTML on the main site or by
[$routeprovider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider)

URL rewriting has to be supported by the server the site is hosted on. 
For this, look at: [$location](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location)